# BSOD: driver_power_state_failure; can't find cause Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I have a notebook, ASUS ROG G750JM, with Windows 8.1 64 bit, that I've been using for a few months.  Three or four times, absolutely random, I get a BSOD with the message: driver_power_state_failure...  I check the dump file in Windows folder, but it's empty.

My question: is there a way to track all activity, so if a BSOD occurs I can see why it crashed and what needs to be repaired?

Comment: without a dmp we can't see the cause. Make sure you have set a pagefile, Windows needs it to create dumps.

Comment: I know you can't see the cause, thats why I am asking how to log it, and yes, pagefile is enabled

Comment: how large is the pagefile?

Comment: it is automatically managed by the system, and I have 16Gb ram

Comment: do you see the large file C:\Windows\Memory.dmp? Also try to change the dump type from automatic dump to kernel or minidump.